# Ubuntu will only boot from boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a MSI laptop and I wanted to use as a dual boot with Windows. Because my SSD space was limited, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the HDD of the laptop which is different from where Windows is installed. The problem is, if I put the HDD as the disk to seek boot from as first priority, grub shows just fine, but when I start Ubuntu, it just freezes. However if I put Windows Boot Manager as the first item in the boot sequence and then access grub by the boot menu, Ubuntu works just fine.

It's been a hassle just trying to install Ubuntu, and I have no clue for solving this issue.